# How to dynamically target UI Elements in Appcelerator?

Tags: titanium-alloy, appcelerator-titanium

Targeting an Alloy element is easy with

**views.xml:**

```
<Label id="targetID1"/>
<Label id="targetID2"/>
<Label id="targetID3"/>
```

**controller.js:**

```
$.targetID1.backgroundColor = "red";
$.targetID2.backgroundColor = "green";
$.targetID3.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

**But is there a way to dynamically pass the target ID to a function and set the values in this function?** In particular, I would like to change the background color of the last selected object.

For instance something like:

```
var selectedObject;

function clickOnObject(e) {
selectedObject = e.source.id;
return selectedObject;
}

changeBackgroundColor(selectedObject)

//should change the background color of the selected object passed to the function

function changeBackgroundColor(id) {
    $.id.backgroundColor = "orange" //this does not work
}
```

I found this ([Select dynamically generated element by id in Titanium Appcelerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068169/select-dynamically-generated-element-by-id-in-titanium-appcelerator/35068348#35068348)) but I am not sure if this is the same thing.

I have multiple fields and used a switch statement. This is of course quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you could use 
`selectedObject = e.source` without the id. Then you have the whole object inside your variable. Inside the changeBackgroundColor you would use id without the $.

e.g. this works:

```
var obj;

function fn(){
    obj.title = "testasdf"
}

$.btn1.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    obj = e.source;
    fn();

});
$.btn2.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    obj = e.source;
    fn();
});
```

with two buttons created inside the index.xml. But you could use this without `var obj` and just pass e.source to `fn()` as a parameter. Depends on your use-case